# Moving row values contains specific string to new column in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, shift

I am restructuring the data frame. The sample data frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Stats'] = ['Def duels', 'Def duels Won','Back passes', 'Back passes[Acc]','Dribbles', 'Dribbles[Suc]']
df ['Value'] = [5,2.5,60,55,5,2]
```

I want to create a new column which only contains the string such as 'Won','Acc' and 'Suc'. The expected data frame is as follow:

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
s=df.Stats.str.contains('Won|Acc|Suc')
df['New']=df.Stats.where(s,'')
df.Stats=df.Stats.mask(s,'')
df
         Stats  Value               New
0    Def duels    5.0                  
1                 2.5     Def duels Won
2  Back passes   60.0                  
3                55.0  Back passes[Acc]
4     Dribbles    5.0                  
5                 2.0     Dribbles[Suc]
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution:

```
# initialize Stats1 with empty strings
df['Stats1'] = ''

# copy values from `Stats`
df.iloc[1::2,-1] = df['Stats']

# replace the copied values with empty strings
df['Stats'] = np.where(df['Stats1'].ne(''), '', df['Stats'])
```

Output:

```
         Stats  Value            Stats1
0    Def duels    5.0                  
1                 2.5     Def duels Won
2  Back passes   60.0                  
3                55.0  Back passes[Acc]
4     Dribbles    5.0                  
5                 2.0     Dribbles[Suc]
```

Answer (score 2):

using `str.contains` with `np.where`

```
df['stat1'] = np.where(df['Stats'].str.contains('won|acc|suc',case=False),df['Stats'],'')
df['Stats'] = np.where(df['Stats'].str.contains('won|acc|suc',case=False),'',df['Stats'])


print(df)

         Stats  Value             stat1
0    Def duels    5.0                  
1                 2.5     Def duels Won
2  Back passes   60.0                  
3                55.0  Back passes[Acc]
4     Dribbles    5.0                  
5                 2.0     Dribbles[Suc]
```

Comment: Hi All, Really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.